# Unable to extract Azure function from the build artifact

Tags: .net, azure-devops, yaml, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 solution that consists of 4 web projects and several other DLLs. I used an azure-pipeline.yml file for deployment.

Recently, I added an Axure function v4 that also targets the 4.8 framework. Now, I'm struggling to add this to a build pipeline.

Here is my VSbuild@1 task

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build Solution'
  env:
    SONAR_DOTNET_ENABLE_CONCURRENT_EXECUTION: true
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
    maximumCpuCount: true  

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: Publish Build Artifacts
  artifact: drop
```

Currently, the web projects are placed in the "_PublishedWebsites" folder within the artifact. However, the Axure function is placed directly in the root folder, making it difficult to extract separately.

If I do the following:

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive Function'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/$(functionName)/bin/Release/net48/*'
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(functionName).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
```

I get the error because bin folder doesn't exist.

Is there a way to place only the Function-related content into a separate folder? This would allow me to extract and include it in another artifact for the deployment stage. Alternatively, are there any other methods to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is a property that is set at the project level and lives outside of the pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may use the predefined template on the classic pipelines:

[image]

You may specify only your function app project to build:

[image]

Then check the yaml definition:

[image]

The default yaml definition:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build project'
  inputs:
    projects: FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1.csproj
    arguments: '--output publish_output --configuration Release'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'publish_output/'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

The results:

[image]

The downloaded artifact:

[image]